# heroku is giving me Method not allowed

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mlab

Okay, so I've been on this problem for hours now with no idea how to solve this, since I'm just a newbie. I was following a UDEMY course titled WEBDEVBOOTCAMP by Colt Steele. On the deployment section, every time I deploy using Heroku, this gives me a **"Method not allowed"**. I've been following Colt's ways from scratch and that's why I wonder how come it's like this.

---

These are the Heroku logs that I've been receiving:

```
2017-08-07T21:45:10.990742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-07T21:45:14.881336+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-07T21:45:14.881350+00:00 app[web.1]: > v1@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-07T21:45:14.881352+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-07T21:45:14.881351+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-07T21:45:16.594550+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-08-07T21:45:16.594555+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production 
environment, as it will leak
2017-08-07T21:45:16.594556+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-08-07T21:45:16.610398+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-08-07T21:45:16.612243+00:00 app[web.1]: The Yelp Camp Server is up!
2017-08-07T21:45:16.665653+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-08-07T21:45:16.914410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-07T21:54:00.075655+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `ls` by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-07T21:54:03.051279+00:00 heroku[run.4055]: Awaiting client
2017-08-07T21:54:03.090885+00:00 heroku[run.4055]: Starting process with command `ls`
2017-08-07T21:54:03.268924+00:00 heroku[run.4055]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-07T21:54:08.289699+00:00 heroku[run.4055]: Process exited with status 0
2017-08-07T21:54:08.303853+00:00 heroku[run.4055]: State changed from up to complete
2017-08-07T22:16:51.093190+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-08-07T22:16:51.093810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-08-07T22:16:52.026960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-07T22:16:52.187881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-07T22:38:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-07T22:38:44.152229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-08-07T22:38:43.802847+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8174904f by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-07T22:38:43.802847+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-07T22:38:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-08-07T22:38:45.764651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-07T22:38:48.251552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-07T22:38:48.251586+00:00 app[web.1]: > yelpcamp@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-07T22:38:48.251586+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-07T22:38:48.251587+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-07T22:38:49.001981+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-08-07T22:38:49.001994+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-08-07T22:38:49.001995+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-08-07T22:38:49.018239+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-08-07T22:38:49.020061+00:00 app[web.1]: The Yelp Camp Server is up!
2017-08-07T22:38:49.043200+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-08-07T22:38:49.214038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-07T23:10:56.925104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-08-07T23:10:56.925706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-08-07T23:10:58.007504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-07T23:10:58.359969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-08T04:47:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T04:47:45.285929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-08-08T04:47:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-08-08T04:47:45.069248+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T04:47:45.069248+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f14ef4fc by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T04:47:46.628278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-08T04:47:48.774464+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-08T04:47:48.774484+00:00 app[web.1]: > yelpcamp@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-08T04:47:48.774485+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-08T04:47:48.774486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-08T04:47:49.444240+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-08-08T04:47:49.444256+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-08-08T04:47:49.444256+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-08-08T04:47:49.454406+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-08-08T04:47:49.455893+00:00 app[web.1]: The Yelp Camp Server is up!
2017-08-08T04:47:49.472576+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-08-08T04:47:49.919585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-08T05:21:42.640479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-08-08T05:21:42.641117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-08-08T05:21:43.112034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-08T05:21:43.397138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-08T05:35:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:35:34.046061+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:35:34.046061+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 52579a31 by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:35:34.347211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-08-08T05:35:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-08-08T05:35:36.040512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-08T05:35:38.881422+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-08T05:35:38.881446+00:00 app[web.1]: > yelpcamp@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-08T05:35:38.881447+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-08T05:35:38.881448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-08T05:35:39.981312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-08T05:35:39.914694+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-08-08T05:35:39.914717+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-08-08T05:35:39.914718+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-08-08T05:35:39.932988+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-08-08T05:35:39.935319+00:00 app[web.1]: The Yelp Camp Server is up!
2017-08-08T05:35:39.967512+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-08-08T05:49:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:49:31.423119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-08-08T05:49:31.425641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-08-08T05:49:31.128129+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 98890a0e by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:49:31.128129+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user lao_tabudlong@yahoo.com
2017-08-08T05:49:32.024642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-08T05:49:32.234319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-08-08T05:49:20.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-08-08T05:49:33.865572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-08-08T05:49:36.912525+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-08-08T05:49:36.912549+00:00 app[web.1]: > yelpcamp@1.0.0 start /app
2017-08-08T05:49:36.912550+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-08-08T05:49:36.912550+00:00 app[web.1]: `enter code here`
2017-08-08T05:49:38.250325+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-08-08T05:49:38.250352+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-08-08T05:49:38.250353+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-08-08T05:49:38.270747+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:17) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-08-08T05:49:38.273329+00:00 app[web.1]: The Yelp Camp Server is up!
2017-08-08T05:49:38.314596+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-08-08T05:49:38.342241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: You might be accessing https://git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git instead of  https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 67):

From the Q&A on the webdevbootcamp video:

"Make sure you are trying to access the correct link that gets printed to the console. You shouldn't try to load the link which ends with .git since that is just the repository location.

Your link should look like https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/"

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem. Check your url, you might be opening the one which ends in `.git`. Instead go to your heroku dashboard and open the app from there using the correct url.

Answer (score 4):

This Problem Bacicaly comes when you are using wrong link

**Your link should be like https://test-name.herokuapp.com/**

Answer (score 1):

With reference to Matt's answer: -

Even if the deployment is successful, but you have not defined a html as to how the webpage should look like, then you get 'Method not allowed', meaning, 
"https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/" will have "Method not allowed".

But there is a way you can test if the deployment is done okay and you are getting Response 200.

Open jupyter notebook and run:
Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/create-an-api-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-using-flask-and-heroku-67a011800c50

In short :

```html
import requests
import json 
# local url
url = 'https://your-app.herokuapp.com/'

# sample data
data = {'Pclass': 3
      , 'Age': 2
      , 'SibSp': 1
      , 'Fare': 50}
data = json.dumps(data)

send_request = requests.post(url, data) #should get : Response 200

print(send_request.json())# should get predicted result
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while deploying a golang web app on heroku. The root cause of the issue was with how i frame the url. The url generated by heroku consisted of a trailing "/" and i was constructing the url as "heroku_url" + "/login" which resulted in heroku_url//login, try removing a / from heroku_url or from your route and give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Before deploying your app make sure your project is on the main branch.

[image]

Refer: [Git Branches](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-branches).