# There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400)

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I hosted a Springboot app on Heroku. Build and deploy works perfectly fine. However, I see this error whenever I want to access the method. `There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).`It works perfectly fine on Postman if I use loclhost but throws error using the Heroku's app.

Here is what the controller looks like. I am guessing this is where the issue is coming from.

.

```
..
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public ResponseEntity<AddResponseDTO> addUser(@RequestBody AddUserDTO addUserDTO) throws ApplicationException {
        AddResponseDTO response = userService.saveUser(addUserDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

}
```

What do you think I can I do make the api work on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was trying to access a POST REQUEST it will definitely throw such error. But the mistake here was that, I was trying to work with a local database.Thus, I created a shared cluster using Mongo Atlas, updated the configuration in my application.properties, I added the variable config to Heroku and everything works just fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The issue not with the Springboot controller. check your Heroku configurations like below.

```
=== <app_name>
Git Url:       git@heroku.com:<app_name>.git
Web Url:       https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/
```

Comment: follow below link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561987/heroku-is-giving-me-method-not-allowed

Comment: You might be accessing git.heroku.com/your-app-name.git instead of your-app-name.herokuapp.com

Comment: follow above link you will get some idea

Comment: This is not the issue at all.