# Method Not Allowed heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, web-deployment

Hello I am deploying for the first time with heroku, and I have a problem.
When doing `git push heroku master` everything works correctly, but when entering the site through the browser it shows me only the message of  `Method Not Allowed`

About the project: It is made with nodejs, express, postgres and sequelize on the backend side and with react on the front side.

The database is already uploaded and is working correctly! but when uploading the project it doesn't work

when doing `heroku logs -n 200` it returns me

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.59.1 to 7.59.2.
2021-12-28T00:46:51.552641+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:46:51.552641+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:46:55.112224+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:46:55.112224+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:47:57.250526+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-amorphous-18095) by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:47:57.250526+00:00 app[api]: Running release v3 commands by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:47:57.275444+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-amorphous-18095 completed provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T00:47:57.275444+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:10:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:10:38.372557+00:00 app[api]: Deploy abd73b84 by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:10:38.372557+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:10:38.387597+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:10:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-28T01:10:41.897243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-28T01:10:43.543463+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:43.543478+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 start /app
2021-12-28T01:10:43.543478+00:00 app[web.1]: > per-env
2021-12-28T01:10:43.543478+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:43.561920+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: per-env: not found
2021-12-28T01:10:43.568721+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-12-28T01:10:43.568931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-12-28T01:10:43.569020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-12-28T01:10:43.569124+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:10:43.573632+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce@0.1.0 start: `per-env`
2021-12-28T01:10:43.573685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:10:43.573770+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-12-28T01:10:43.573839+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce@0.1.0 start script.
2021-12-28T01:10:43.573890+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-28T01:10:43.579537+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:43.579638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-28T01:10:43.579689+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-12-28T01_10_43_574Z-debug.log
2021-12-28T01:10:43.703276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-28T01:10:43.758598+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-28T01:10:43.763138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-28T01:10:46.370206+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-28T01:10:47.472121+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:47.472132+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 start /app
2021-12-28T01:10:47.472132+00:00 app[web.1]: > per-env
2021-12-28T01:10:47.472132+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:47.476034+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: per-env: not found
2021-12-28T01:10:47.479992+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-12-28T01:10:47.480158+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-12-28T01:10:47.480221+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-12-28T01:10:47.480286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:10:47.482318+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce@0.1.0 start: `per-env`
2021-12-28T01:10:47.482361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:10:47.482406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-12-28T01:10:47.482446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce@0.1.0 start script.
2021-12-28T01:10:47.482482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-28T01:10:47.486127+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:10:47.486197+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-28T01:10:47.486228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-12-28T01_10_47_483Z-debug.log
2021-12-28T01:10:47.615077+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-28T01:10:47.682401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-28T01:19:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:19:21.617612+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 481231e4 by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:19:21.617612+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T01:19:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-28T01:19:22.754313+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-28T01:19:25.218296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-28T01:19:26.154715+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.154724+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 start /app
2021-12-28T01:19:26.154724+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run server
2021-12-28T01:19:26.154725+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.358957+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.358959+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 server /app
2021-12-28T01:19:26.358959+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon server.js
2021-12-28T01:19:26.358960+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.363664+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2021-12-28T01:19:26.367517+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-12-28T01:19:26.367670+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-12-28T01:19:26.367739+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-12-28T01:19:26.367822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:19:26.370782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce@0.1.0 server: `nodemon server.js`
2021-12-28T01:19:26.370823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-12-28T01:19:26.370876+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-12-28T01:19:26.370924+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce@0.1.0 server script.
2021-12-28T01:19:26.370966+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-28T01:19:26.373409+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.373479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-28T01:19:26.373515+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-12-28T01_19_26_371Z-debug.log
2021-12-28T01:19:26.381218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-12-28T01:19:26.381440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-12-28T01:19:26.385033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce@0.1.0 start: `npm run server`
2021-12-28T01:19:26.385078+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-12-28T01:19:26.385133+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-12-28T01:19:26.385190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce@0.1.0 start script.
2021-12-28T01:19:26.385249+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-28T01:19:26.388004+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T01:19:26.388101+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-28T01:19:26.388128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-12-28T01_19_26_385Z-debug.log
2021-12-28T01:19:26.532464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-28T01:19:26.580646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-28T02:10:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:10:55.246466+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:10:55.246466+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 408cc0e7 by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:10:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-28T02:10:56.665889+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-28T02:10:59.192072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-28T02:11:00.408464+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T02:11:00.408486+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 start /app
2021-12-28T02:11:00.408486+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-12-28T02:11:00.408486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T02:11:00.924625+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 02:11:00 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:19:9
2021-12-28T02:11:00.925307+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 02:11:00 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:19:9
2021-12-28T02:11:00.925975+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-28T02:11:00.925976+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-28T02:11:00.925976+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-28T02:11:01.052123+00:00 app[web.1]: listen on port 4747
2021-12-28T02:11:59.280273+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-12-28T02:11:59.310519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-12-28T02:11:59.457957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-12-28T02:11:59.513246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-28T02:11:59.517764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-28T02:12:01.776449+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-12-28T02:12:02.697087+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T02:12:02.697102+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce@0.1.0 start /app
2021-12-28T02:12:02.697102+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2021-12-28T02:12:02.697103+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-28T02:12:03.109575+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 02:12:03 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:19:9
2021-12-28T02:12:03.109947+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 28 Dec 2021 02:12:03 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:19:9
2021-12-28T02:12:03.110335+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2021-12-28T02:12:03.110336+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2021-12-28T02:12:03.110336+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2021-12-28T02:12:03.270410+00:00 app[web.1]: listen on port 4747
2021-12-28T02:13:02.321588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-12-28T02:13:02.385589+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-12-28T02:13:02.423619+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2021-12-28T02:13:02.555802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2021-12-28T02:13:02.619496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-28T02:24:06.811349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=devmusic-e.herokuapp.com request_id=b963cdda-25f1-40ad-ad48-453d230fd1d0 fwd="181.165.54.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-28T02:24:07.567128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=devmusic-e.herokuapp.com request_id=e4181dab-522f-4d25-8cf7-571e2f47abb2 fwd="181.165.54.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-28T02:27:20.713535+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:27:23.597696+00:00 heroku[run.8831]: Awaiting client
2021-12-28T02:27:23.612526+00:00 heroku[run.8831]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-12-28T02:27:23.768779+00:00 heroku[run.8831]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-28T02:27:26.931258+00:00 heroku[run.8831]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-28T02:27:26.991577+00:00 heroku[run.8831]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-28T02:27:32.365105+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:27:35.374067+00:00 heroku[run.9154]: Awaiting client
2021-12-28T02:27:35.382164+00:00 heroku[run.9154]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-28T02:27:35.392551+00:00 heroku[run.9154]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-12-28T02:27:38.713398+00:00 heroku[run.9154]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-28T02:27:38.759105+00:00 heroku[run.9154]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-28T02:30:02.434663+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user ivanleodomin00@gmail.com
2021-12-28T02:30:05.749584+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Awaiting client
2021-12-28T02:30:05.759879+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: State changed from starting to up
2021-12-28T02:30:05.766832+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2021-12-28T02:30:09.092845+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: Process exited with status 127
2021-12-28T02:30:09.145510+00:00 heroku[run.5828]: State changed from up to complete
2021-12-28T02:33:06.079727+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=devmusic-e.herokuapp.com request_id=49e83d77-278f-470d-9f6b-fa7706e1584c fwd="181.165.54.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-28T02:33:06.764438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=devmusic-e.herokuapp.com request_id=3b4a6dac-235a-4a9f-b6e5-0a29ff44616e fwd="181.165.54.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561987/heroku-is-giving-me-method-not-allowed

Comment: it didn't help me but thanks!